# How would I allow guests to add comments and ratings to existent entries?

Tags: entries, comments, guest

I have a page with a bunch of images that I'd like people to rate and comment on.  The rating would be a select custom field, and the comment would be a simple textarea custom field.

I'd like to allow guests to submit their ratings and comments, but the Guest Entries plugin doesn't seem to handle editing.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 6):

Using the Guest Entries plugin, it is not possible. Using a custom plugin is possible though. The trick is that each guest needs to be identifiable in some way. Otherwise every guest would be able to edit every comment, and you would have chaos (or a wiki).

So if you want them to be able to edit a comment and still not have to log in, you can create a custom plugin that replicates much of the functionality of the Guest Entries plugin. Adding on to that, you could create a unique string stored in a separate table linked to that entry. This string would be used to give the anonymous user a unique edit link. This would keep the comment reasonably safe.

Though in all honesty, you would be better served by having users log in or using an external commenting service (if you are avoiding buying a higher Craft version).

Comment: Thanks for the response Bryan, I thought that might be the case.  The comments wouldn't be seen by any users...ideally they'd submit them and the comment would be stored in a matrix row for the entry.  Unfortunately, a custom plugin is outside the scope of my abilities.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried this but here is an idea.

Set up a separate channel for the comments and use an [entries field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields) to link the submitted comments to your images. You can use the [guests plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) for this as you don't have to edit existing entries.

Before you added your comment to Bryans answer, I thought you want your guests to be able to edit their comments after submitting them. This would indeed demand a custom plugin.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion!  I don't want them to edit their comments, but they would just need to edit the entry.  So I'm publishing 10 entries, and they would "edit" the entry by adding a comment.  At no point would they be creating a new entry.  Your entries field link is an interesting idea, I'll give it a shot...thanks!

Comment: @user2048433 did it work out for you?